Is it possible to use different scales?
How to combine left and right scales in one indicator for MACD, RSI, and Stochastic in Pine Script?
I have a script that combines MACD, RSI, and Stochastic, and I want to have the following setup:
MACD with its scale on the left.
RSI and Stochastic with their scales on the right.
I've tried adjusting the plot() function and hline() for scale alignment but couldn't achieve the desired result.

You can't do that. Try it Rescaling
